# Redirect sqlplus shell output to file

Tags: bash, file, redirect, logging, sqlplus

I'm trying to redirect the sqlplus output to a file via the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash
    
${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba <<-EOF
  select 1 from dual;
  exit
  EOF 
   > test.log
```

the file is created but it's empty. The user who runs this script is able to write in the
current directory, so no access right problem.

It works if I'm using oracles spool command, but why is the above syntax not working?

Comment: Of course there is no access problem for the directory, otherwise you would not get an empty file. Does sqlplus write anything to stderr? Is sqlplus asking you for a password? What happens if you don't redirect but doing everything interactively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An EOF must end a line, but you can redirect before the here doc:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
    
${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba >> test.log <<-EOF
    select 1 from dual;
    exit
EOF
```

I don't have `sqlplus`, but tested it with `cat`:

```sh
$ cat > derp.txt <<-EOF
        aaa
        bbbb
        cccc
EOF
```